# RPostgreSQL: losing time from datetime variables with dbGetQuery

Tags: r, postgresql, datetime

I'm currently working on a PostgresQL database and when I try to import into R, I'm losing the time component of the datetime variables that are in format "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss":

```
bp_sql_query <- "SELECT DISTINCT itemid, datetime FROM chartevents WHERE 
                 valueuom = 'mmHg';"
bp_chartevents_itemid <- dbGetQuery(con, bp_sql_query)

   itemid   datetime
   1         03/01/2018
   2         05/06/1985
```

I'm new to sql and postgresql databases in general. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the schema has it as a datetime and not just a date variable?

Comment: We did put [tests for correct datetime conversion in about a decade ago](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL/blob/master/RPostgreSQL/tests/datetimeTests.Rout.save) so this should not be a RPostgreSQL limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It seems to be a time zone related issue. Setting `Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC')` before executing the query solved the problem for me.